# What forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> consumer) method does in ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I was looking into ArrayList implementation and found forEachRemaining method. 
What is the use of this or when we call this method?

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
{
    //...
    //...
    private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
        //...

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> consumer) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(consumer);
            final int size = ArrayList.this.size;
            int i = cursor;
            if (i >= size) {
                return;
            }
            final Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
            if (i >= elementData.length) {
                throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
            }
            while (i != size && modCount == expectedModCount) {
                consumer.accept((E) elementData[i++]);
            }
            // update once at end of iteration to reduce heap write traffic
            cursor = i;
            lastRet = i - 1;
            checkForComodification();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc description?

Comment: Check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-

Comment: It's not on `ArrayList`, it's on `Iterator`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` doesn't have `forEachRemaining`, the iterators and such it returns do.

From [the documentation for `Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining(java.util.function.Consumer)):

> Performs the given action for each remaining element until all elements have been processed or the action throws an exception. Actions are performed in the order of iteration, if that order is specified. Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Using Iterator if you traverse on list using `next()` then it will return the next element in that list. So suppose you didn't traverse on complete list and called `forEachRemaining()` then it will remaining elements in list which not traversed.

A Demo

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
list.add("four");
list.add("five");
//added five element in list

Iterator<String> iterator =  list.iterator();

//visiting two elements by called next()
System.out.println("Printed by next():" + iterator.next());
System.out.println("Printed by next():" + iterator.next());

//remaining un-visited elements can be accessed using forEachRemaining()
iterator.forEachRemaining(s -> {System.out.println( "Printed by forEachRemaining():" + s);});
```

Output:

```
Printed by next():one
Printed by next():two
Printed by forEachRemaining():three
Printed by forEachRemaining():four
Printed by forEachRemaining():five
```